# $.each() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you can help me.

I have this code

```
var marcadores = [<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?>];

$.each(marcadores, function( i, value ) {
  events.push({title: value[i][0], start: new Date(value[i][1], value[i][2]-1, value[i][3],value[i][4]),color: '#9b59b6'});
});
;
```

It's not working at the moment, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: var marcadores = [<?php echo $listeDesPoints; ?>];

Comment: What do you mean not working? Does it throw an exception? Does it produce anything in the javascript console?

Comment: I assume `marcadores` is suppsoed to be an array or object. are you sure `echo $listeDesPoints;` is outputting exactly what javascript will recognize? to my understanding `echo $listeDesPoints;` will just output *"Array"* if it was an array

Comment: What does `$listeDesPoints` contain? Can you show the actual script, as it shows up in the browser (View Source, show us what's in `var marcadores = ...`)

Comment: Yes sir, javascript recognize $listeDesPoints

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
  {
     if($listeDesPoints!='') 
   $listeDesPoints.=','; 
     $listeDesPoints.='['.'"'.$row[0].'"'.','.'"'.$row[3].'"'.','.'"'.$row[2].'"'.','.'"'.$row[1].'"'.','.'"'.$row[4].'"'.']';
       }

Comment: Are you outputting two sets of [ ]?  You have the set in the Javascript as well as the set within the PHP $variable.

Comment: Looks like you need to either not wrap the PHP embed with [] or you need to remove the [] from the $listeDesPoints string. You're doing a foreach on an array that contains an array, instead of on an array.

Comment: Here is the complete code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/45eec828a3f7bfdadb9e

Comment: @MarianoHernandez Did you try taking out one set of [ ] like we suggested? On either line 12 or 17 in your gist

Comment: Hi Alan, the [] are not the problem, that works fine, what doesnt work is the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the way you're interpreting `$.each()` arguments: you take `value` as if it was the entire `marcadores` array, while in fact it is only its current item.

So you only have to drop `[i]` from each object's building factor.
Results in this:

```
$.each(marcadores, function( i, value ) {
  events.push({
    title: value[0],
    start: new Date(value[1], value[2] - 1, value[3], value[4]),
    color: '#9b59b6'
  });
});
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error message? Or what is the resulting output?

Comment: Events its still empty after doing that

Comment: Can you post a sample of 2 rows **real content**, in order to directly test?

Comment: ["Peluqueria","2015","11","21","13"],["Veterinaria","2015","12","14","18"] This is the result after doing alert(marcadores)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/13dc89277a6780c609c5 This is the original code, maybe it helps you, on line 87 are the events loaded one by one, i need those events to be captured from the array i make.

Comment: It can only come from something else in your running context. So if take your [https://gist.github.com/anonymous/45eec828a3f7bfdadb9e] as reference, can you insert `alert(marcadores);` at line 18, then `alert(events.length);` at line 22 and tell us what you get? BTW what puzzles me is: I can't see your `events` variable declaration anywhere. What about that? Sure you don't get any error message?

Comment: Oops! If `events.length` is declared undefined, so first it's pretty normal you don't get it populated. Also it means that, in some way, you didn't declared it as you believe: maybe at a wrong place so it's not declared yet when the culprit code executes? Or in a closure so it's not visible when we need it for this same code?

Comment: Is there another way to fill up the events array without using $.each ?

Comment: I've tried this, but its not working for (i=0; i<marcadores.lenght;i++) {
events.push({
    title: marcadores[i][0],
    start: new Date(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2] - 1, marcadores[i][3], marcadores[i][4]),
    color: '#9b59b6'
  });
 };

Comment: I supplose you mean the `for()` solution did fail too, yet because `events` is undefined. Normal, IMO. Anyway, this might remove any doubt: insert a `console.log(typeof events)` just before your `$.each()`. If it says `undefined` as I expect, then you **must** look for how your `events`variable declaration fails.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your php output correctly it looks something like

```
// an array of date
var marcadores = [
  ['title', 2, 10, 15, 9],
  ['other title', 3, 10, 14, 12]
  //etc
];
```

You're iterating over this data structure to create objects. You have an array of arrays, with your inner array more of an object

```
// also make sure you initialize events to be an array, otherwise you can't call push on something that is not an array
var events = [];

$.each(marcadores, function(i, value) {
    // value here is the current item in your iteration
    events.push({
        title: value[0],
        start: new Date(value[1], value[2]-1, value[3], value[4]),
        color: '#9b59b6'
    });
});
```

Also you'd make your life much easier if you built up a multidemnsional array in php then json_encoded it.

```
<?php
// clipped
$str="select asunto, day(fecha),month(fecha),year(fecha),hour(fecha) from agenda where id_persona = 77";
$consulta= mysql_query($str); 
$listeDesPoints = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $listeDesPoints[] = array(
        'title' => $row[0],
        'day' => $row[1],
        'month' => $row[2],
        'year' => $row[3],
        'hour' => $row[4]
    )
}
?>
var marcadores = <?php echo json_encode($listeDesPoints); ?>;
```

Then you output is

```
 // an array of date
 var marcadores = [{
        title: 'title',
        day: 1,
        month: 10,
        hour: 15
    }
  //etc
];
```

And iteration reads much better

```
$.each(marcadores, function(i, value) {
    // value here is the current item in your iteration
    events.push({
        title: value.title,
        start: new Date(value.day, value.month-1, value.year, value.hour),
        color: '#9b59b6'
    });
});
```

Comment: *"You're echoing a php array. I'm not sure what that will do.*" you'll just output the word *"Array"* to the page

Comment: Fair enough. I tried it on 5.6 and got an error. `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Same result as before, the $.each is the problem here, it dosnt fill the events array

Comment: What is the actual output from php? You're using php to write javascript, so look at the intermediate output by `View Page Source`

Comment: events: [
           { 
           title:'Gaming Day',
           start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                             color: '#9b59b6'
                          }
          ]

Comment: This is how it was at the begging and i need to use elements from that array to fill up the events array, so i can use those fields to complete the calendar.

Comment: I get it now. You're iterating over an array with a single object in it. You don't need to do that, it's making things more complex for you.

Comment: And what would it be the solution Nathanael ?

Comment: I looked at your gist, it looked like `$listeDesPoints` was a string in php, so your output was correct.

Comment: Updated my answer. Double check that you are declaring `events` to be an Array. And @cFreed answer is correct on your `value` inside the iteration.

Comment: @NathanaelSmith: +1 for the JSON-encoded solution, which brings much better readability!

Comment: Nathanae when i use your codification Marcadores is Empty when i do alert(marcadores)

Comment: Is there another way to fill Events without using $.each ?

Comment: Sure, assuming you aren't supporting a terribly old browser, you can for, forEach, map, or even reduce.

Comment: Im really really close now !!! Would you tell me why marcadores.lenght is undefined ?

Comment: Doing this works perfectly for (i=0; i<2;i++) {
events.push({
    title: marcadores[i][0],
    start: new Date(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2] - 1, marcadores[i][3], marcadores[i][4]),
    color: '#9b59b6'
  });
 };

Comment: doing this gives me nothing for (i=0; i<marcadores.lenght;i++) {
events.push({
    title: marcadores[i][0],
    start: new Date(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2] - 1, marcadores[i][3], marcadores[i][4]),
    color: '#9b59b6'
  });
 };

Comment: @MarianoHernandez: could you explain?

Comment: @cFreed Yes of course, looks like (I Don't know even why but it works haha) Marcadores is an object, so , i replaced the first code using $.each and used this one var events = [];
for (i=0; i<Object.keys(marcadores).length;i++) {
events.push({
    title: marcadores[i][0],
    start: new Date(marcadores[i][1], marcadores[i][2] - 1, marcadores[i][3], marcadores[i][4]),
    color: '#9b59b6'
  });
 };
Once I Was there, I've tried to use marcadores.lenght to get through the array, but it wasn't working ( Marcadores.lenght = undefined) exchanged it to OBject.keys(marcadores).lenght, and it worked !

Comment: @MarianoHernandez: thanks for the precision. So then I understand what I couldn't figure out from your previous post. But something keeps puzzling me: `$.each()` [can iterate both on arrays and objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) so it should have been working fine also, once corrected by dropping the useless `[i]` from factors! Any idea?

Comment: i literaly have no idea why it wasnt working, it bothers me haha, but yeah. If i figure it out why it didnt work i'll let you know, thanks for all the responses and for helping me !

Comment: @cFreed Hi Man :) It's me again haha, i have another question for you. I'm using HTML <input type="time" name="usr_time"> in a form, when i click on submit it shows the hour perfectly but, you know how to get the hour and the minutes for separate ?

Comment: @MarianoHernandez: not sure to clearly understand what you're looking for, since it seems pretty easy to extract hours and minutes from a time-formatted string. Anyway, you shouldn't ask a different question through comments in another, previous, question. Instead ask a really independant question, and add enough precision to make us understand what is exactly your issue.